# How to get changed value itself only when the value's specific parameter changed using flutter provider

Tags: flutter, provider

I have StreamProvider.value and want to take the Provider's value only when the specific parameter of the Provider's value changed. I know how to get changed value itself returned from the provider when the value changed, but I want to know how to get changed value itself only when the value's specific parameter changed.

Here is my code snippet.

LocationModel has location data like city, street name, country

```
StreamProvider<LocationModel?>.value(
      value: locationService.locationStream,
      initialData: null,
      child: MaterialApp(
             ~
```

I checked below code works, but actually I want LocationModel value itself, not city data of LocationModel only when the city data of locationModel changed.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String location = context.select((LocationModel? locationModel) => locationModel?.city) ?? '';
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can listen to changes only in the city.

```
 final city = context.select((LocationModel? p) => p.city ?? '');
 Text('${city}');
```

Comment: This code works when LocationModel changed. I know the way to get it when LocationModel's city changed.

Comment: this will return whole locationmodel instead of city only. if anything in location model updates this will update that  value too.

Comment: I want locationmodel only when the city of locationmodel changed. The screen rebuilds so many times according to the location changed because the street of locationmodel changed many times. This is not my goal. But, thanks!